# Can't start Hadoop from an init.d script

Tags: linux, centos, boot, init.d, hadoop

I'm using CentOS 6.2.  I'm trying to start Hadoop from an init.d script, but it's failing.  This is what I see in boot.log :

```
Retrigger failed udev events                               [  OK  ]
Enabling Bluetooth devices:
starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop--namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop--jobtracker-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

Here's my init.d script :

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          hadoop
# Required-Start:    sshd
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: hadoop
# Description:       start hadoop daemons
### END INIT INFO

# source function library
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

RETVAL=0

case "$1" in
    start)
        /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/start-all.sh
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
    stop)
        /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/stop-all.sh
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Ya blew it"
        RETVAL=2
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

when I type in chkconfig --list hadoop from the command line, I get this :

```
hadoop          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

I created a user called hadoop, and all my hadoop stuff lives in /home/hadoop/hadoop/.  I have the UID bit set on all the scripts in /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/, so start-all.sh and stop-all.sh should run as the hadoop user.

From the command line, I can successfully execute start-all.sh, stop-all.sh, and /init.d/hadoop.  I can execute the scripts as the hadoop user or root, and they work fine.  However, when /init.d/hadoop is called during the boot process, it fails.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors seem pretty obvious...it appears that the `hadoop` startup scripts use `ssh` to connect (possibly as a different user) and start things up:

```
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

And if you look at the startup, you'll see that `sshd` is starting *after* `hadoop`:

```
starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop--namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop--jobtracker- 
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

The solution is to make sure that `sshd` starts first (although frankly using ssh to localhost to start the service seems like a bad idea).  You can change the startup order of things by looking in the appropriate runlevel directory (e.g., `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d`) and changing the number after the `S` (as in `S55sshd`).  Make sure that your shutdown order is correct, too (that is, make sure `hadoop` is configured to stop *before* `sshd`).

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for the n00b question -- this was my first experience writing init scripts :)